# When I'm trying submit getting error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

TrainingLightningAppWithController -

```html
<aura:application >
    <c:TrainingLightningAppWithControllerCompo/>
    
</aura:application>
```

TrainingLightningAppWithControllerWithCompo-

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" 
                > 
    <ui:inputText
     label='FirstName'
      aura:id='EnterFirstName' 
      placeholder='Enter first name'
                  />
<ui:inputText
  label='LastName' 
 aura:id='EnterLastName'
 placeholder='Enter last name'
                  />
  <ui:button 
   aura:id='Buttonforaction' 
   label='Submit'
 press="{!c.getOutLookName}"  />
    
  <ui:outputText 
aura:id="NameToDisplay" 
    value=""/>    
</aura:component>
```

TrainingLightningAppWithControllerWithCompo.js

```js
({
    getOutLookName : function(component) {
        var firstName = component.find("EnterFirstName").get("v.value");
        var lastName = component.find("EnterLastName").get("v.value");
        var fullName = firstName ,lastName;
        var OutputName = component.find("NameToDisplay");
        OutputName.set("v.value",fullName );
    }
})
```

error---

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Unable to find action 'getOutLookName' on the controller of c:TrainingLightningAppWithControllerCompo
Failing descriptor: {c:TrainingLightningAppWithControllerCompo}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why are setting `fullName = firstName,lastName;`

```
var fullName = firstName + ' ' +lastName;
```

I think problem shouldn't occur for this reason, here fullName will have value of firstName. If firstName is null then it will take lastName. Apart from this I don't see any issue in your code.